# Обновление slug в django

Tags: python, django, slug

```
category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 220)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='category_name', unique=True, db_index=True)
```

Есть поле slug. И там уже записано значение которое соответствует названию. Но когда я меняю название, slug не меняется. Подскажите что делать? Как обновить slug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить `always_update= True`
Вот так будет:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='category_name', unique=True, db_index=True, always_update=True)
```

А чтобы вручную править то можно еще добавить: `editable=True`